# How does one promote a third queen in an over-the-board game?

Tags: rules, pawn-promotion, otb-chess

Most chess sets come with only one spare queen, and according to the video in the question [Is holding the opponent's captured pieces legal or allowed?](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/33316/is-holding-the-opponents-captured-pieces-legal-or-allowed), one cannot use an upside-down rook because is effectively the same as promoting to a rook.

If two queens are already on the board, how can one promote a third one?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Under USCF rule 8F7:, it *is* acceptable to place a rook upside-down if a spare queen is not available.

> If the desired piece is not available to replace a promoted pawn, the player may stop both clocks in order to locate that piece and place it on the board. A player who cannot quickly find such a piece may request the assistance of the director. It is common practice, however, to play using an upside-down rook for a second queen. In the absence of the player’s announcement to the contrary, an upside-down rook shall be considered a queen.

Under FIDE rules, you can't use an upside-down rook as a spare queen, but you can find the answer hidden in the section about the clocks:

> 6.11.2  A player may stop the chessclock only in order to seek the arbiter’s assistance, for example when promotion has taken place and the piece required is not available.

Comment: This actually happened a few days ago in the game Krzysztof - Demchenko, 2021 European Blitz Championship.  There is a video of the game here: https://youtu.be/_bfamBcHwDk?t=1100

Answer (score 22):

You pause the clock, call an arbiter and an additional queen will be provided.